How to move split chunk into entry
do you know how to move common chunks to an entry point? Previously in webpack-4 you could have the same name for the entry point and for the common chunk. But in webpack-5 I have such error:
ERROR in SplitChunksPlugin
Cache group "vueVendors" conflicts with existing chunk.
Both have the same name "vue-vendors" and existing chunk is not a parent of the selected modules.
Use a different name for the cache group or make sure that the existing chunk is a parent (e. g. via dependOn).
HINT: You can omit "name" to automatically create a name.
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to allow to use an entrypoint as splitChunk. This is no longer allowed when the entrypoint is not a parent of the selected modules.
Remove this entrypoint and add modules to cache group's 'test' instead. If you need modules to be evaluated on startup, add them to the existing entrypoints (make them arrays). See migration guide of more info.

The main problem here is that I use assets-manifest plugin and I manually add chunks to html so I need "vue-vendors" to be inside entrypoints section in the manifest.
Thanks.
